# Activating filters in a ListBox with some toggle buttons

Tags: wpf, xaml, filter, listbox, togglebutton

Ok I have a ListBox binding to a property from the ViewModel.
It has been populated with a Caliburn.Micro.BindableCollection like this

```
public BindableCollection<QueueTask> QueueTasks
        {
            get
            {
                return this._queueProcessor.Queue;
            }
        }
```

The queue task has some properties like this:

```
public class QueueTask : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private StatusCode _status;
        private int _completedPercent;

        public StatusCode Status
        {
            get => _status;
            set
            {
                _status = value;
                this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Status);
            }
        }

        public int CompletedPercent
        {
            get { return _completedPercent; }
            set
            {
                _completedPercent = value;
                this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CompletedPercent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now as you can see one of his properties is a StatusCode  enum

```
public enum StatusCode
    {
        Waiting = 1,    
        Processing,    
        Finished,    
        Error
    }
```

Now the real question is...
How I can (in the View) filter the ListBox to show only a portion of the list based in the StatusCode using 4 ToggleButtons for each of the StatusCode. So if I have pressed (or activate) the button for finished and error only show in the ListBox those who meet that condition. If they are all active, show everyone. And if there is none marked then do not show anything.

I know that it can be acomplished using an ICollectionView. If it can be in xaml better, although it can be in the code behind the View. The idea I had was to have several ICollectionView one binding to the other. As a chain and each toggle button will activate or deactivate the filtering for each one (although I still have to see how to do it even for a single toggle button). I don´t know if this is the best approach so any help is welcome.

Sorry for my english I only speak spanish...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thanks to Sean Sexton for this post 
https://wpf.2000things.com/2014/01/14/986-filtering-a-listbox-using-a-collectionviewsource/

now the solution using CollectionViewSource is simple (more or less). It is implemented in the view with some code.

First created (the CollectionViewSource is binding to the full queue):

```
<Window.Resources>        
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding QueueTasks, Mode=OneWay}" x:Key="FilteredQueueTasks" IsLiveFilteringRequested="True">
            <CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
                <clr:String>Status</clr:String>
            </CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Then bind the ListBox to this CollectionViewSource (it is simplified). Then it only show the tasks already filtered by the CollectionViewSource

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FilteredQueueTasks}}" />
```

The code behind the view looks like this (is large)

```
public partial class QueueView : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public QueueView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void QueueTasks_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            StatusCode status = ((QueueTask) e.Item).Status;

            switch (status)
            {
                case StatusCode.Waiting:
                    e.Accepted = showWaiting;
                    break;
                case StatusCode.Processing:
                    e.Accepted = showProcessing;
                    break;
                case StatusCode.Finished:
                    e.Accepted = showFinished;
                    break;
                case StatusCode.Error:
                    e.Accepted = showWithErrors;
                    break;
                case StatusCode.Warning:
                    e.Accepted = showWithWarnings;
                    break;
                default:
                    e.Accepted = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private bool showWaiting = true;

        public bool ShowWaiting
        {
            get => showWaiting;

            set
            {
                showWaiting = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShowWaiting));
                ((CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["FilteredQueueTasks"]).View.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private bool showProcessing = true;

        public bool ShowProcessing
        {
            get => showProcessing;

            set
            {
                showProcessing = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShowProcessing));
                ((CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["FilteredQueueTasks"]).View.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private bool showFinished;

        public bool ShowFinished
        {
            get => showFinished;

            set
            {
                showFinished = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShowFinished));
                ((CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["FilteredQueueTasks"]).View.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private bool showWithErrors = true;

        public bool ShowWithErrors
        {
            get => showWithErrors;

            set
            {
                showWithErrors = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShowWithErrors));
                ((CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["FilteredQueueTasks"]).View.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private bool showWithWarnings = true;

        public bool ShowWithWarnigs
        {
            get => showWithWarnings;

            set
            {
                showWithWarnings = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShowWithWarnigs));
                ((CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["FilteredQueueTasks"]).View.Refresh();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["FilteredQueueTasks"]).Filter += QueueTasks_Filter;
        }
    }
```

Then every ToggleButton attach to it like this:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-1,0,5,5">
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding ShowWithErrors, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:QueueView}}}">
                <Image Source="Images/Error.png" Margin="1" />
            </ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding ShowWithWarnigs, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:QueueView}}}">
                <Image Source="Images/Warning.png" Margin="1" />
            </ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding ShowFinished, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:QueueView}}}">
                <Image Source="Images/Complete.png" Margin="1" />
            </ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding ShowProcessing, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:QueueView}}}">
                <Image Source="Images/Working.png" Margin="1"/>
            </ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding ShowWaiting, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:QueueView}}}">
                <Image Source="Images/Movies.png" Margin="1" />
            </ToggleButton>
        </StackPanel>
```

It updates the filter when any of the ToggleButtons changes her state and when any item in the queue update her Status. For the LiveFilter to work the property must implement INotifyPropertyChanged so it can notify the view for changes.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately give a link to [source](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11P26KYwPwmxcC45niL6MIJTncaiP_JL5).

How it looks visually can be seen in [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1mNY.png)

For the filter value, I created the `FilterValue` model.
This is necessary to find out when our properties change.

```
public class FilterValue
{
    private bool _value;

    public bool Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            ValueChanged?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public event Action ValueChanged;
}
```

In the `QueueTask` class, I added the `TaskName` property to make it clear what the task are in the list.

```
public class QueueTask : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private StatusCode _status;

    private int _completedPercent;

    private string _taskName;

    public StatusCode Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set
        {
            _status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Status));
        }
    }

    public int CompletedPercent
    {
        get { return _completedPercent; }
        set
        {
            _completedPercent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CompletedPercent));
        }
    }

    public string TaskName
    {
        get { return _taskName; }
        set
        {
            _taskName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Status));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then I created a list with all the elements `_allQueueTasks` and a view list of `QueueTasks`.
The collection for testing I fill in the method `FillTempData ()`.
Also I created the `Filters` dictionary with all possible `StatusCode` values. It is filled in the `FillFilters ()` method.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<QueueTask> _allQueueTasks;

    private List<QueueTask> _queueTasks;

    public Dictionary<StatusCode, FilterValue> Filters { get; set; }

    public List<QueueTask> QueueTasks
    {
        get { return _queueTasks; }
        set { _queueTasks = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(QueueTasks)); }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        FillTempData();
        FillFilters();
    }


    private void FillFilters()
    {
        Filters = new Dictionary<StatusCode, FilterValue>();
        foreach (StatusCode code in Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusCode)))
        {
            var newFilter = new FilterValue();
            newFilter.ValueChanged += FilterOnValueChanged;
            Filters.Add(code, newFilter);
        }
    }

    private void FilterOnValueChanged()
    {
        var filtredItems = _allQueueTasks.Where(task => Filters[task.Status].Value);
        QueueTasks = new List<QueueTask>(filtredItems);
    }

    private void FillTempData()
    {
        _allQueueTasks = new List<QueueTask>()
        {
            new QueueTask() { Status = StatusCode.Waiting, TaskName = "WaitingTask1"},
            new QueueTask() { Status = StatusCode.Waiting, TaskName = "WaitingTask2"},
            new QueueTask() { Status = StatusCode.Processing, TaskName = "ProcessingTask1"},
            new QueueTask() { Status = StatusCode.Processing, TaskName = "ProcessingTask2"},
            new QueueTask() { Status = StatusCode.Finished, TaskName = "FinishedTask1"},
            new QueueTask() { Status = StatusCode.Finished, TaskName = "FinishedTask2"},
            new QueueTask() { Status = StatusCode.Error, TaskName = "ErrorTask1"},
            new QueueTask() { Status = StatusCode.Error, TaskName = "ErrorTask2"},
        };
        QueueTasks = new List<QueueTask>();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Well, the last step is the layout of the visual part.
I used the `ItemsControl` to display the `ToggleButton`.
To display the list itself, I used the `ListBox`.

```
...
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel></viewModel:MainViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton Margin="5" Height="25" Width="100" Content="{Binding Key}" IsChecked="{Binding Value.Value}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding QueueTasks}" DisplayMemberPath="TaskName"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Ok it works as adviced, a little late for me. The only problem I found is, the listbox is not refreshed when the StatusCode change in the individual QueueTask. For now I'm going to work with this other solution https://wpf.2000things.com/2014/01/14/986-filtering-a-listbox-using-a-collectionviewsource/. I using it now and it works ok for me. The only concern is about performance with a lot of QueueTask but for as much as 500 it work fine. Any way I'm going to try to implement your solution, it looks more OOP than mine. :)

Comment: Are you about the sorting speed? I think this decision will not be slow. If you have some work in QueueTask, then you need to consider separately this class) 
I apologize for my English, I am from Russia.)

Comment: In fact I don't do any sort only filter the queue to show any QueueTask as needed. But for example in my code when I do the filter it needs to accept or not each item in the queue I'm think it can be slow in a very large queue, maybe not my case, but who knows. In the case of your code, you rebuild the queue each time, in a fast changing queue I think it can be bad... I don't really know I'm so new to this.

Comment: The only changing thing affecting the filter is the Status, but in the near future I want to implement a text search (filter) in the queue, and it can be easely implemented in my code (at least for my knowledge). About language no problem, I'm Cuban and when needed I love google translate.